# c# social management

Tags: c#, user-interface, social-networking

I was wondering, is there a way I can create an application which for example updates both my facebook and my twitter at the same time?

So for example I have a GUI which has a similar interface as my facebook profile (or whatever), and I want to post a comment on my profile through my GUI, so I write a line in a GUI textbox, press apply and it adds the post to my facebook profile and at the same time to my twitter for example.

I know this sounds silly since u can media link both pages, but that's not my true goal, I'm just wondering if this is possible so I can extend it to other facebook services.

Comment: Sorry about that, lost track of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

[facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf)

[twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/)

And (.NET related) :

[C# Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/)

[C# Twitter API(unofficial)](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. I don't see how this wouldn't be.
Also, I suggest you have a look at Seesmic Desktop for an application that does that which use Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You would have to use the APIs exposed by Facebook and Twitter. You can then post let's say status on both twitter and facebook by calling update status related APIs of both Twitter and Facebook on the `apply` button click event.

You can use [this](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) for Twitter and [this](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) for Facebook both are C# clients for Twitter and Facebook respectively.